# Unable to issue command/read data on remote host from Elixir using sshex framework

Tags: ssh, erlang, elixir

MacOS 12.5.1 (M1 Max)
Elixir 1.14.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)

I am trying to read some status data from a network switch within my Elixir application over ssh. I am attempting to do this using the SSHEx framework.

I am able to connect fine (returns ok, and I can see an open session on the switch), but when I issues a command I am unable to read any response, and it times out waiting.

To confirm I have started :ssh under Extra Application.

Here is the code I am using initially, I'm aware it's not ideal at the moment, but it should at least be getting me some output.

```
defmodule FibreTestUi.Ssh do
  defp connect do
    SSHEx.connect(
      ip: '192.168.1.1',
      user: 'admin',
      password: '!Password',
      modify_algorithms: [
        {:append, [{:kex, [:"diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1"]}]},
        {:append, [{:public_key, [:"ssh-rsa", :"ssh-dss"]}]}
      ]
    )
  end

  def list_port_status do
    {:ok, conn} = connect()
    SSHEx.cmd!(conn, 'show ssh', exec_timeout: 15000)
  end
end
```

All I get back is:

```
** (RuntimeError) {:error, "Timeout. Did not receive data for 15000ms."}
    (sshex 2.2.1) lib/sshex.ex:100: SSHEx.cmd!/3
    iex:2: (file)
```

If I ssh into the switch manually, I am able to execute the command fine.

```
user@comp ~ % ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 admin@192.168.1.1


FS#show ssh
Connection Version Encryption       Hmac         Compress   State           Username
         0     2.0 aes128-ctr       hmac-sha1    none       Session started admin
FS#
```

If I pick another random device (ransom raspberry pi), and connect with a basic 'echo hello' I get a response fine.

```
defmodule FibreTestUi.Ssh do
  defp connect do
    SSHEx.connect(
      ip: '10.11.xx.xx',
      user: 'pi',
      password: 'password',
      modify_algorithms: [
        {:append, [{:kex, [:"diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1"]}]},
        {:append, [{:public_key, [:"ssh-rsa", :"ssh-dss"]}]}
      ]
    )
  end

  def list_port_status do
    {:ok, conn} = connect()
    SSHEx.cmd!(conn, 'echo hello', exec_timeout: 5000)
  end
end

"hello\n"
```

So it seems to be something specific to this device, but I can't really work out what that would be. Anyone got any thoughts?

Thanks

**Edit 1**

I have also tried doing this directly using :ssh with the following code:

```
  def send_command do
    {:ok, ssh_pid} =
      :ssh.connect('192.168.1.1', 22,
        user: 'admin',
        save_accepted_host: false,
        silently_accept_hosts: true,
        password: '!Password',
        modify_algorithms: [
          prepend: [kex: [:"diffie-hellman-group1-sha1", :"diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1"]],
          prepend: [public_key: [:"ssh-rsa", :"ssh-dss"]]
        ]
      )

    {:ok, chn} = :ssh_connection.session_channel(ssh_pid, 5000)

    _success = :ssh_connection.exec(ssh_pid, chn, 'show ssh', 5000)

    # for _ <- 0..1 do
    receive do
      {:ssh_cm, ^ssh_pid, value} -> IO.inspect(value)
    after
      5000 ->
        IO.puts(:stderr, "No message in 5 seconds")
    end

    :ok = :ssh.close(ssh_pid)
  end
```

The response I get is this, for every command, no matter what command I send.

```
iex(20)> FibreTestUi.Ssh.send_command    
{:data, 0, 0,
 <<2, 83, 67, 80, 58, 32, 83, 67, 80, 32, 83, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 32, 83,
   101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 32, 105, 115, 32, 100, 105, 115, 97, 98, 108,
   101, 33, 10>>}
```

Comment: If it helps, the latest data response is actually `<<2>> <> "SCP: SCP Server Service is disable!\n"`.